# Where is the bin folder of GWT Internal Jetty Server in DevMode?

Tags: gwt, jetty

I need to put some property files (config file required by a library) in the starting path of the Jetty server in DevMode but could not figure out where to put them. Where should I put them?

I googled but no luck for that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this perhaps relevant for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993215/adding-external-resources-to-gwt-dev-mode-server-jetty

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven in your project, placing them in the src/main/resources should work.

Otherwise put it in your WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your project set up information. Maven? Also mention whether property file is for app or jetty and what you are trying to achieve.

Also you can try putting up the properties file in web-inf/classes if it is project specific.

I am guessing you are not using any standard GWT project set up. It will be very difficult to proceed further even if you get this solved. I recommend you should go with gwt standard set up. You can reference GWT samples folder from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-2.5.0.zip&can=2&q=).

[image: If]

Use Hello project set up as template. If you are beginner also read up on https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools#webAppCreator.

Comment: It is GWT compiler and eclipse internal build. The property file is read from Property class so it is related to the deployment context

Comment: I am guessing you are using ant build file with your set up and source code in in src/com . I am still no able to make out whether the property file you are reading is to be used for your application or for your jetty set up.